# Generate an Image from Title

Tags: image-transforms, image

I would like to **generate image automatically on entry save**, using the entry Title and a specified image as a background.

I was thinking to use the **Preparse Field plugin**, but it seems like it's not possible to use the Image Magick commands inside the Preparse fields.

**Imager X** plugin is also not able to do this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

While you don't state the purpose of the image, one might assume that you want to use it as a social share image?
If so, [this article might come in handy](https://ghijk.co.uk/blog/generate-dynamic-social-share-images-in-craft-cms).

Even if your intented use is different I think the above would be a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks for the article.

I followed all the instructions, but for some reason the images are not being generated at all. I'm not getting any error, so I'm not sure If the job gets triggered. Any Idea how can I test this out?

Comment: Ok, It seems like I moved forward a little. Now I'm getting an error _Class "modules\jobs\GenerateSocialCard" not found_. I have the file GenerateSocialCard.php under modules/jobs and I have the _class GenerateSocialCard extends BaseJob specified_.

Comment: I got stuck, so I added [new question](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/40903/class-modules-jobs-generatesocialcard-not-found) about this to describe the problem little bit more further. I would be glad If you could take a look. Thanks.