# Class "modules\jobs\GenerateSocialCard" not found

Tags: modules

Following [this article](https://ghijk.co.uk/blog/generate-dynamic-social-share-images-in-craft-cms), I'm trying to generate an image from html on Entry Save, but I'm getting an error when trying to push a job *GenerateSocialCard* to the Craft queue.

I'm using the default Module. Here is the code:

```
Queue::push(new GenerateSocialCard([
  'elementId' => $element->id 
]));
```

I have GenerateSocialCard.php under modules/jobs with the GenerateSocialCard class defined:

```
<?php

namespace modules\jobs;

use Craft;
use craft\helpers\App;
use craft\queue\BaseJob;
use Spatie\Browsershot\Browsershot;

class GenerateSocialCard extends BaseJob
{

    public $elementId;

    public function execute($queue)
    {
        Browsershot::url(getenv('PRIMARY_SITE_URL') . '/x/' . $this->elementId)
            ->setNodeBinary(App::env('NODE_BINARY'))
            ->setNpmBinary(App::env('NPM_BINARY'))
            ->windowSize(1200, 675)
            ->waitUntilNetworkIdle()
            ->save(getcwd() . '/web/img/fakty' . $this->elementId . '.png');
    }

    protected function defaultDescription(): string
    {
        return Craft::t('app', 'Generate the social card');
    }
}
```

I'm still getting an error ***Class "modules\jobs\GenerateSocialCard" not found***

Any Ideas?

Thank you!!

**Modules folder structure:**

```
modules
  - jobs
    - GenerateSocialCard.php
- Module.php
```

**Composer.json**

```
"autoload": {
   "psr-4": {
     "modules\\": "modules/"
   }
},
```

Comment: Looks like the autoloader can't find the PHP file with the class in it – can you post your directory structure (especially the `modules/` folder) and your `composer.json` (especially the `autoload` setup)?

Comment: @MoritzLost

I edited the question with all the information you requested.

Comment: Hm, that all looks correct … does the error go away when you run `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: @MoritzLost Nope. It didn't help ... I'm still getting the same error.

Btw, I was getting _Class "modules\GenerateSocialCard" not found_, so I tried to add `use modules\jobs\GenerateSocialCard;`, then I got the _Class "modules\jobs\GenerateSocialCard" not found_.